# Ruby on Rails - ActiveRecord::Base.transaction, no id on show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, transactions

I have a form that allows a user to input a keyword on each line on a text box, this is then split up and I create seperate records for each word.

I am using the following `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` to ensure my validation is met and the records are only added if validation passes for each keyword entered.

```
respond_to do |format|
  begin
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      @keywords.each &:save!
      logger.info @keywords
      format.js   { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: group_keywords_path }
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError => e
    format.js   { render json: @keyword.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

The problem I am having is this, on `show.js.erb`, `@keyword` doesn't have an `id` but has all of its other data, why?

If log the output of `@keywords` before I render the show action I can see the following

`[#<Keyword id: 141, group_id: 14, keyword: "a keyword", created_at: "2015-06-15 11:28:31", updated_at: "2015-06-15 11:28:31">]`

Why isn't this `id` being passed on?

Comment: try to reload object before showing it, like ar_object.reload

Comment: no, before you passing it to renderer